# How to write a fairness algorithm in Javascript using circular arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, circular-buffer

My kid's baseball team has 13 kids. Each kid is supposed to rotate through the positions so that they all get equal time at each position. We have 4 outfielders, by the way, as these kids are only 7 years old.

I tried to write a little Javascript algorithm to rotate them through fairly. I came up with the following, but it doesn't seem to be as fair as I thought it would be, and it's confusing. I am sure there's an easier way. Suggestions?

```
var people = new Array("Amelie","Avery","Brennan","Clayton","Devin","Flynn","Haydn","Jack","Kai","Liam","Max","Maxi","Sterling");
    var people_copy = people.slice(0);
    var jobs = new Array("Pitcher","Catcher","Third Base","Short Stop","Second Base","First Base","Right Field","Ctr Right","Ctr Left","Left");
    var jobs_copy = jobs.slice(0);
    var result_set = new Array();

    for(i=0;i<jobs_copy.length;i++){
        j = i%jobs.length;
        result_set[j] = new Object();
          for(h=0;h<people_copy.length;h++){
                  if((jobs[0]) && (people[0])){
                    jobby = jobs[0].trim();
                    persony = people[0].trim();
                    result_set[j][jobby] = persony; 
                  }
                  var shifted = people.shift();
                  people.push(shifted);

                  var jobs_shifted = jobs.shift();
                  jobs.push(jobs_shifted);    
            }
            var shifted = people.shift();
            people.push(shifted);
          }

    for(i=0;i<result_set.length;i++){

        console.log("\nIteration: " + (i+1));

        for(h=0;h<jobs_copy.length;h++){
            l = jobs_copy[h];
            console.log(l + '=' + result_set[i][l]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just create two lists (players, jobs), then rotate one of the lists...?  i.e. `jobs = [a, b, c]`, `players = [1, 2, 3]`, then next week, `jobs = [b, c, a]`, `players = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Because you might have fewer jobs than players or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Init the list.
var people = ["Amelie","Avery","Brennan","Clayton","Devin","Flynn","Haydn","Jack","Kai","Liam","Max","Maxi","Sterling"];
var jobs = ["Pitcher","Catcher","Third Base","Short Stop","Second Base","First Base","Right Field","Ctr Right","Ctr Left","Left"];

for (var c=people.length; c>0; c--) {
    var firstToLast = people[0]; // Backup first value
    people.shift (); // Remove from the list 
    people.push(firstToLast); // Append the name to the end
    console.log (people); // ["Avery", "Brennan", "Clayton", "Devin", "Flynn", "Haydn", "Jack", "Kai", "Liam", "Max", "Maxi", "Sterling", "Amelie"]

    // To print a list of jobs
    for (var i=0; i<jobs.length; i++) {
        console.log (people[i] + ': ' + jobs[i]);
    }
    console.log ('-----');
}
```

If all you want is to rotate the people list, this should do the job.

Edit: Loop added.

Comment: Missing a loop there - I want to show as many iterations as it takes to have each person do each job.

Comment: Loop added to the answer :3

Comment: That's it! Funny, I can't upvote until I get more reputation points. But alas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are more players than jobs, I've added `Not playing` jobs to your array so that we can simply rotate the jobs and have everything line up nicely.

Below is a simple solution that rotates the jobs array by a specified number:

```
var people = ["Amelie", "Avery", "Brennan", "Clayton", "Devin", "Flynn", "Haydn", "Jack", "Kai", "Liam", "Max", "Maxi", "Sterling"];
var jobs = ["Pitcher", "Catcher", "Third Base", "Not playing", "Short Stop", "Second Base", "First Base", "Not playing", "Right Field", "Ctr Right", "Ctr Left", "Left", "Not playing"];


function getPositions(gameNumber) {
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        console.log("Player: " + people[i] + ", " + jobs[(i + gameNumber) % jobs.length]);
    }
}
```

If you wish to play 10 games, then invoke the function 10 times with the `gameNumber` argument ranging from 1-10.

You can also shuffle the initial players array, just to make sure everything is fair. For more information: [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: If we get a new player, or shrink the jobs, the algorithm should "just work" without having to add things like "not playing."

Comment: I like Jixun's solution up above :)

Comment: @Mreider, I hope you know that the solution you selected will leave the same person benched up to three games in a row though. :)